# Android Retrofit 2 login with Oauth 2.0 - Spring Boot Backend

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-boot, retrofit2

I am trying to login and get a token using retrofit 2, from my API which is using Spring Boot 2.

The problem I am having is that it works in Postman, but I am getting the 403 status code in Android.

This is the code I am using in Postman:

[image: Postman setup]

I have been trying this two ways, but i am getting the same 403 status code:

TokenResponse class:

```
public class TokenResponse {
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    private String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String accessToken;

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
}
```

Service (the two ways i have tried):

```
  @POST("/oauth/token/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<TokenResponse> getToken(@Field("client_id") String clientId,
                                 @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                                 @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                                 @Field("username") String username,
                                 @Field("password") String password);
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/token/")
    Call<TokenResponse> getToken2(@Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                                 @Field("username") String username,
                                 @Field("password") String password,
                                 @Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

And the class where I am making the request (also with the two ways I have tried):

```
private void oauth2Example() {
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://ip:8080");

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        UserService service = retrofit.create(UserService.class);

        //way number one
        byte[] credentials = "androidapp:12345".getBytes();
        String basicAuth = "";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials).trim();
        }
        Call<TokenResponse> call = service.getToken2("password", "j@h.com", "12345", basicAuth);
      //FINISH way number 1

        //way number two
        Call<TokenResponse> call = service.getToken("androidapp", "12345", "password", "j@h.com", "12345");
       //FINISH way number 2

       //RESULT
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TokenResponse> call, Response<TokenResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, response.body().getAccessToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"error " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TokenResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I commented the two ways I am trying (i am not using the same "call" variable at the time of course), but in both ways, as I said, I am getting the 403 error.

What should I modify in order to be able to get the bearer token I can get from Postman, but I just get a 403 in Android?

Comment: Two notes: It's generally better to use `authorization_code` (you can install a URI handler for the redirect), and I would check to see if Retrofit has specific built-in support for the `Authorization` header as it's such a common use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in order to avoid the 403 forbidden was change this

```
@POST("/oauth/token/")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<TokenResponse> getToken(@Field("client_id") String clientId,
                             @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                             @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                             @Field("username") String username,
```

To this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers(
            {"Authorization: Basic yourAuthHere",
                    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    )
    @POST("oauth/token")
    Call<JWT> oauthToken(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("grant_type") String grant_type);
```

That way I was able to login with a Spring boot backend using oauth 2.0